# Ambiguity in formatting operation in python

Tags: python

```
def hello(input, *args):
    s=input.replace('%0','{0}')
    v=s.format(args)
    return v

assert "hello stack"==hello("hello %0","stack")
```

I am getting ASSERTION ERROR and  the output is : "hello ('stack',)"
  instead of  "hello stack".....WHY???

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce this on Python 3.4 and on [Python 2.7](http://ideone.com/kyaKGQ)

Comment: Do not name your variable `input`, that is a Python functino name

Comment: Is there an asterisk in `def hello(input, *args)`? That would lead to the error you posted.

Comment: @unutbu looks like the edit just now has confirmed that :p

Comment: So if your your function uses `*args`, why not pass that on to `str.format()` with `s.format(*args)`?.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that generates the error, you have the following as your function header:

```
def hello(input, *args):
```

This will turn `args` into a tuple of all positional arguments. The code you have pasted in the question does not generate the error:

```
>>> def hello(input, args):
...    s = input.replace('%0', '{0}')
...    v = s.format(args)
...    return v
...
>>> hello('hello %0', 'stack')
'hello stack'
>>> def hello2(input, *args):
...     s = input.replace('%0', '{0}')
...     v = s.format(args)
...     return v
...
>>> hello2('Hello %0', 'stack')
"Hello ('stack',)"
```

To make it work, you need to expand the tuple: `v = s.format(*args)`.

I'm not sure what the actual purpose of this code is, because it will only take the first argument; no matter how many actual arguments you sent to the method:

```
>>> def hello3(input, *args):
...     s = input.replace('%0', '{0}')
...     v = s.format(*args)
...     return v
...
>>> hello3('hello %0', 'stack', 'world')
'hello stack'
```

This is because the `{0}` binds to the first argument `.format()`.

Comment: Might just want to add that to fix it: `v = s.format(*args)`